# QuantumGIS MapServer and Web Client can not display standard HelloWorld Map

Tags: webclient, qgis, mapserver

I have Kubuntu 12.04.
I've installed QGIS MapServer according to the [tutorial](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial#Webserver-configuration):

```
apt-get install qgis-mapserver libapache2-mod-fcgid
```

(And I also have a working apache2 server)

Then I've got a QGIS Web Client from [git](https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client), configured it according to these steps:

> - sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-fcgid
> - cp apache-conf/qgis-web-client.conf.tmpl apache-conf/qgis-web-client.conf
>
> Update the paths in the copied file then:
>
> - cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
> - ln -s  .
> - sudo a2enmod rewrite
> - sudo a2ensite qgis-web-client.conf
> - sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
> - Check the symlink in cgi-bin is correct
> - Check the QGIS libs are in your /etc/ld.so.conf path
> - Copy site/index.xml and check paths match your system OR   Modify index.html and point your browser to that

I don't understand what must be in the **/etc/ld.so.conf** path - maybe it is a problem? If I'm right, what am I must do to solve the problem? I have installed QuantumGIS but not from the source, but can it be so critical?

And also I have **Internal Server Error** on http://local.host/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities. Is it normal?

I've copied the *qgis-web-client/js/GlobalOptions.js.templ-4326* to *qgis-web-client/js/GlobalOptions.js* and nothing else.

So, here is a problem:
I go to my http://local.host/qgis-web-client/site/, select the map (HelloWorld, NaturalEarth - doesn't matter), then I have a QGIS-Browser window. Very pretty but without any maps and layers - only message "*Loading Map...*". I've opened Chrome Debugger and followed the link http://local.host/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/web/qgis-web-client/projects/helloworld.qgs&&_dc=1373135966552&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetProjectSettings.

And I've seen this:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.3.0">
<ServiceException code="">
Configuration file problem : perhaps you left off the .qgs extension?
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

So, the question is how to display map in QGIS Web Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just couldn't understand what pathes are to be checked in index.html - I had to replace */home/web/qgis-web-client/* with my actual Client path and the same thing is to be done with my *GlobalOptions.js* file.

Еhe last but not the least thing to do is to switch off the GetCapabilities using: `var useGetProjectSettings = false;` (because of "**Set this to false to use GetCapabilities for older QGIS Server versions (<= 1.8).**" comment before that string)